# Java to MS access DB connection error

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc

I have tried to load JdbcOdbcDriver Using Netbeans 8 but am getting following error (included error message).Can some help me on this ?. Explain me how to add library in Net beans 8.

```
import java.io.*;

import java.sql.*;

 public class test {

 public static void main(String [] args) 
 {    

 try 
   {
    System.out.println("JDBC-ODBC driver loading......");
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver") ;
    System.out.println("JDBC-ODBC driver loaded ok.");


} catch(Exception ex)
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
  } 
  }

ERROR :
 run:
     JDBC-ODBC driver loading......
       java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver
       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:359)
       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:348)
       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:347)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
       at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:258)
       at abd.pkg1.test.main(test.java:14)
           BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Comment: Are you using Java8? The JDBC/ODBC bridge has been removed in Java 8

Comment: Then how to connect Java and Access DB in NetBeans 8

Comment: Either use a different JDK (NetBeans 8 does not mean you have to use Java 8) or use other libraries, e.g.: http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver Exception occuring ? why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984438/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-sun-jdbc-odbc-jdbcodbcdriver-exception-occurin)