# How to access Excel as Database using Java 8

Tags: java, excel, ojdbc

I am using Java 8.

When i am trying to access Excel data(basically this is my test data) through jdbc-odbc, i am getting "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"

And also i am trying to access data as non DSN.

I surfed net and came to know that Oracle deprecated support to jdbc-odbc.

So what is the easiest way to access this Excel data using Java?

```
Connection con=null;
    Statement stmt=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;
    String query = "select TestScript from [TS 360 Scripts$]";

    try
    {
        Class.forName( "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver" );
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:;Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver(*.xlsx)};DBQ=D://TS 360 Script with Count.xlsx");


        stmt=con.createStatement();
        rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while(rs.next())
        {
            System.out.println(rs.getString("TestScript"));
        }

        con.close();
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21481078/4385913)

Comment: Joan Colmenero, as i mentioned in my post i am using Java 8. I am getting exception at connection creation statement. con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:odbc:" +
                    "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};" +
                    "DBQ=C:\\Users\\Gord\\Desktop\\test.xlsx;" +
                    "ReadOnly=0;");

Comment: Look this answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22996068/4385913)...

Comment: Joan Colmenero, as i mentioned i am trying to access Excel as Database, when i am trying UcanAccess, i am getting "net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: Decoding not supported.  Please choose a CodecProvider which supports reading the current database encoding" Exception.

Answer (score 2):

Dont Access Excel file as a database. Instead use a jar such
as Apache POI For Microsoft Documents

Download Link: [Apache POI For MS Docs- Jar](http://poi.apache.org/download.html)

An Example For using this API:

Note: you must add apache poi jar to your build path before running it

```
package com.dd.selenium;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


public class PerformDDTest {

    private static HSSFWorkbook xlWBook;

    private static HSSFSheet xlSheet;

    private static HSSFRow xlRow;

    private static HSSFCell xlCell;

    private static String filePath = "/home/dinesh/";

    private static String fileName = "test.xls";

    private static String url = "http://store.demoqa.com/"; 

    private static String result = "Pass";


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        try {
            FileInputStream xlFile = 
                    new FileInputStream(filePath+fileName);

            //Access the required test data sheet

            xlWBook =  new HSSFWorkbook(xlFile);

            xlSheet = xlWBook.getSheet("Sheet1");

            xlRow = xlSheet.getRow(1);

            String username = xlRow.getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
            String password = xlRow.getCell(2).getStringCellValue();

            FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            driver.manage().window().maximize();


            driver.get(url);

            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='account']/a")).click();

            driver.findElement(By.id("log")).sendKeys(username);
            driver.findElement(By.id("pwd")).sendKeys(password);

            driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();



            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='account_logout']/a")).click();

            Thread.sleep(5000);

            driver.quit();

            setResultCell();


            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(filePath+fileName);

            xlWBook.write(fout);

            fout.flush();
            fout.close();



        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            result = "Failed";
            setResultCell();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }


    private static void setResultCell() {
        xlCell = xlRow.getCell(3, xlRow.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);

        if(xlCell == null ){
            xlCell = xlRow.createCell(3);
            xlCell.setCellValue(result);
        }else{
            xlCell.setCellValue(result);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Dinesh, i badly need it for project purpose. The reason being, i have my test cases and its data in Excel with a flag called "IsExecute", which is Yes or No. I need to find test cases with Yes. Though i may write code with POI, it is easy if we consider above situation treat excel as Database.

Answer (score 1):

Uday- you can easily do whatever you want to do with Apache POI jar

As Your are mentioned your requirement: of all rows having isExecuted String Yes. I tried with this jar.

Try this

```
package com.dd.selenium;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

public class PerformDDTest {

    private static HSSFWorkbook xlWBook;
    private static HSSFSheet xlSheet;
    private static HSSFRow xlRow;
    private static HSSFCell xlCell;
    private static String filePath = "/home/dinesh/";
    private static String fileName = "test.xls";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        try {

            FileInputStream xlFile = new FileInputStream(filePath + fileName);

            // Access the required test data sheet

            xlWBook = new HSSFWorkbook(xlFile);

            // Assuming your data is in Sheet1- if not use your own sheet name
            xlSheet = xlWBook.getSheet("Sheet1");

            // gives row count in sheet
            int noOfRows = xlSheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();

            // gives column count in sheet
            xlRow = xlSheet.getRow(0);
            int noOfColumns = xlRow.getLastCellNum();

            // excelData - 2 dimm array - stores all the excel data -Sheet1 only
            String[][] excelData = new String[noOfRows][noOfColumns];

            // r - row c- column
            for (int r = 1; r < noOfRows; r++) {
                for (int c = 0; c < noOfColumns; c++) {
                    xlRow = xlSheet.getRow(r);
                    xlCell = xlRow.getCell(c);

                    // Here we have complete excel data in an array -excelData-

                    excelData[r][c] = xlCell.getStringCellValue();

                    // System.out.println("row: " + r + " column: " + c);
                    // System.out.println(excelData[r][c]);
                }
            }

            // creating an array to store isExected column
            String[][] isExecuted = new String[noOfRows][1];

            for (int row = 1; row < noOfRows; row++) {
                // here column is always only one
                // so c=0

                // extracting a isExecuted column - and considering it as last
                // column in sheet
                // in your case it is not then - count the column position : use
                // position-1
                // ex: if column position is 7 then use 6 as below
                // isExecuted[row][0]= excelData[row][6];

                isExecuted[row][0] = excelData[row][noOfColumns - 1];

                if (isExecuted[row][0].equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {

                    // accessing complete row -which isExecuted=Yes

                    // *********IMPORTANT*****
                    for (int col = 0; col < noOfColumns; col++) {
                        // prints all the rows where isExecuted column has Yes
                        System.out.println(excelData[row][col]);
                    }
                }

                // System.out.println(isExecuted[row][0]);

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

I used this Excel Data:

```
Test Case Name  Username    Password    Results IsExecute
APACHE_POI_TC   testuser_1  Test@123    Pass    Yes
APACHE_POI_TC   testuser_2  Test@124    Pass    No
APACHE_POI_TC   testuser_3  Test@125    Pass    Yes
APACHE_POI_TC   testuser_4  Test@126    Pass    Yes
APACHE_POI_TC   testuser_5  Test@127    Pass    No
APACHE_POI_TC   testuser_6  Test@128    Pass    Yes
```

Answer (score -1):

This might be a little late but in case you still have the issue you can retain access excel as a db with java 8 using Fillo: http://codoid.com/fillo/

Comment: Sai: This is not an open source tool which can be used under community license.

Comment: @Sam: the link shows that it's released under the Apache License. But unfortunately it does not contain a JDBC driver.