# Java8 compatible issue with JDBC driver

Tags: java, jdbc, java-8

We've tried to execute the java DB snippet in **Java8** installed machine, where I got an exception that `ClassNotFoundException in sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.`

So we have understood that this is because of Removal of *JDBC-ODBC* bridge from **Java8** and that's why the snippet we developed in **Java7** is throwing this type of error.

Here, please confirm whether the same snippet will work if we downgrade the **Java8** to **Java7**? If so, how can we do that downgradation? Is updating the environment variable `PATH` would be fair enough to instruct the machine to use Java7 for execution or we should do something else do?

**Note:** We don't have option for using some other drivers that support **Java8.** So please help us to overcome this situation. Thanks!

Comment: Why use a class from `sun.*` to start with?

Comment: No newer versions of Java will work for you. It is important that your boss understands that resources  must be allocated for fixing your product!

Comment: What OS are you using? What IDE are you using? What CI are you using?

Comment: “We don't have option for using some other drivers that support Java8” Proof by claiming? It’s contradicted by the fact that you are developing against an `interface`.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in this StackOverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22984438/2867032), you will need to omit the `Class.forName()` statement for it to make it work.

Apart from `PATH` variable, for downgrading from Java 8 to Java 7, you would also need to set the `JAVA_HOME` variable. If you use Maven to power your builds, then this variable `JAVA_HOME` will be useful there as well.

Have a look at this article by Java.com giving information on the downgrade.

[Information about reverting to Java 7 after installing Java 8](https://java.com/en/download/help/java_revert.xml)