# Can no longer run jdbc with update

Tags: java, jdbc

I recently updated from java 7 to 8 and jdbc will no longer run.

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"); // classNotFoundException is thrown
```

is what i get now when I run it, where did I go wrong?

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver Exception occuring. Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984438/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-sun-jdbc-odbc-jdbcodbcdriver-exception-occurin)

Comment: Answer can be found here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955256/manipulating-an-access-database-from-java-without-odbc

Cheers.

Comment: JDBC-ODBC bridge is no longer available in Java 8. it will be explained here: docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/bridge.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UCanAccess is a pure Java JDBC driver that allows us to read from and write to Access databases without using ODBC. It uses two other packages, Jackcess and HSQLDB, to perform these tasks.

Answer (score 0):

sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver is Java internal class, it is not documented in the official Java SE javadoc and it should not be used by applications because it may change or totally disappear in a next Java version.

Comment: wrong. It was documented. It was also always advised to not use it for anything except demonstration and educational purposes because it was not considered production quality code. It was also removed in JDK 8.