# odbc driver exception jdk 1.8

Tags: java, eclipse, odbc, driver

i typed a single program to connect to a access database and display a single record.
but when i run the program, there seems to be an issue with the drivers.
(i'm just getting started in java)   [image]
              **  the DNS & table name are correct

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver Exception occuring. Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984438/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-sun-jdbc-odbc-jdbcodbcdriver-exception-occurin)

Answer (score 1):

The JDBC-ODBC bridge driver has been removed from JDK 8.  Any tutorials you see that use Access probably depend on this class.  It's been part of Java for 20 years, so I'm sure you'll find lots of examples that are now obsolete.

You'll either have to buy a JDBC driver for Access or use a real database like MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc.