# MS Access Database: error "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"

Tags: java, exception

HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error

exception

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver
note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0 logs.
```

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984438/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-sun-jdbc-odbc-jdbcodbcdriver-exception-occurin)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the jar-library with the missing driver-class to the glassfish-runtime.

This is a duplicate to:

[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver Exception occurring. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984438/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-sun-jdbc-odbc-jdbcodbcdriver-exception-occurin)

Comment: i add "commons-lang-2.6.jar, commons-logging-1.1.1.jar, hsqldb.jar, jackcess-2.1.2.jar, ucanaccess-3.0.0"

Comment: Sorry, but i don´t know a jar-library with the missing class. I even did not find it on http://search.maven.org and it is not part of my jdk. Classes which package starting with "sun." should be part of the jdk/jre.