# JDBC ODBC bridge driver missing

Tags: java, jdbc

1. I'm using NetBeans 8.2 and trying JDBC ODBC Sample code but there is a problem with Java because the JDBC/ODBC brigde was removed.
2. I searched my problem on the Internet and found that I can use `Jackcess Library` or else I can use this `HXTT` driver, but I don't know how to do it. I'm totally confused and I need help.

   ```
   import java.sql.*;
   public class SampleDatabase {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           try{
               Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
               System.out.println("Drivers are properly loaded");
               String url="jdbc:odbc:abc";
               Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
               System.out.println("Connectionn Established");
               con.close();
           }catch(SQLException e){
               System.out.println("SQL ERROR : "+e);
           }catch(Exception e){
               System.out.println("Connection ERROR : "+e);
           }
       }    
   }
   ```
3. problem solved
4. I was using wrong Driver.
5. Updated code:

   ```
   import java.sql.*;
   public class SampleDatabase {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           try{
               Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
               System.out.println("Drivers are properly loaded");
               String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/world";
               Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","hcpl");
               System.out.println("Connectionn Established");
               con.close();
           }catch(SQLException e){
               System.out.println("SQL ERROR : "+e);
           }catch(Exception e){
               System.out.println("Connection ERROR : "+e);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: what exception are you getting?

Comment: Connection ERROR : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver

Comment: pls take look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984438/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-sun-jdbc-odbc-jdbcodbcdriver-exception-occurin

Comment: I saw that link which you provided @Vaseph. I've put a jar file (com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5.jar) in the same package but still I got the same output.

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5.jar is a JDBC driver specifically for MySQL databases. It won't work with other databases like Access (or SQLite, or SQL Server, ...).

Comment: I visited that link which provided me @GordThompson and I tried to solve my problem that way, currently it is not showing me any result but I'll definitely keep trying that way. Maybe a restart can change my output. And thanks for your suggestion for com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5.jar file.

Comment: If the MySQL driver fixed your problem you never used MS-Access in the first place.

Comment: The JDBC-ODBC bridge has been dropped from Java, and this has nothing whatsoever to do with Netbeans.