# Java & Access Database

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc-odbc

I am trying to select records and view it in a JTable. My records are in Ms Access database locally in my computer. While trying to run the program i am getting an Null point Exception error, pointing my Prepared Statement.
Below is my code

```
try {
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    String sourceURL =
                "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=E:/My Documents/NetBeansProjects/VictoriaMilk/3.accdb;";
    Connection li = DriverManager.getConnection(sourceURL, "Admin", "");
    System.out.println("Connection is: "+li);
    PreparedStatement pstm = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Milk");
    // SLNO, NAMES, QTY, RATE, Deductns, BalPaid
    ResultSet Rs = pstm.executeQuery();

    while (Rs.next()) {
        model.addRow(new Object[]{Rs.getInt(1), Rs.getString(2), Rs.getString(3), Rs.getString(4), Rs.getString(5),
        Rs.getString(6), Rs.getString(7)});
    }

} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(ResultTable.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (SQLException sqle) {
    System.out.println(sqle);
}
```

Comment: Where is `conn` defined?  I see `li` which is what I would have expected you to use.

Comment: please share complete  error log

Comment: @stdunbar suggesting making an answer out of that

Comment: I've put like this private static Connection conn;

Comment: Ok, then where is `conn` assigned?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com//questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: I have assigned my connection on the top like "   private static Connection conn; "

Comment: You get the connection with `li` and not with `conn`.

Comment: @stdunbar  .....iIt worked....Thanks

Comment: The JDBC/ODBC bridge is no longer available in Java 8. See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984438/)

Answer (score 1):

You are opening a new connection and assigning to local `li` variable but moment later you are attempting to `private static Connection con` which is `null`. Use the connection from `li` variable:

```
Connection li = DriverManager.getConnection(sourceURL, "Admin", "");

PreparedStatement pstm = li.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Milk");
```